# Protect ajax posts?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form that users use to add their email address and name to sign up for a newsletter.

On submit an ajax request transmits the data to my database.

Should I use any sort of protection to stop someone else adding entries to the database, eg. if another site linked their form to my ajax request url, then they would be adding data to my database.

How can I stop this?

Comment: Thats when [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) come into play. Other hostnames shoudn't be able to send Ajax Requests to your site by default. Only if you set the specific header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: One cannot easily use your form and store that value in your databse via Ajax post. You might need to check with Cross Domain Ajax,JSONP,CORS related topics. You can still make your form protective by checking whether the form is used in authorized domain only or not.

Comment: Put a token in your form, that you save e.g. in a session serverside. Then only forms having the correct token for that form/script-call might submit the form (correctly). At least this will prevent to just post to your ajax url.

Comment: Six upvotes for this? Seriously?

Answer (score 3):

If you're really serious about it:

- generate a random number for each page, and add it to the form as a hidden field ( and in `$_SESSION` )
- on submission, check that the number matches

Even better, just create a random string, and only send its hash - if you match the hash you get from the form with the one generated from the original string, you have a valid request.

This will kill you caching though, so I cannot really recommend it as a "just do this" solution, depends on your volume.

Comment: +1 Official name of this technique is [cross site request forgery protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). No need to bother about caching because it is POST, it should not be cached anyway.

Comment: @amartynov: the caching issue is not when handling the request, but when generating the form as part of the page - to use the above technique effectively, each user should get his own printed hash/number, which breaks the page cache. There are obviously ways to mitigate that (load the form "block" via AJAX after the page, use the same hash for all requests for X minutes, etc)

Comment: got you. However most probably you want to protect forms which have dynamic content, so again should not be cached.

Comment: You're talking about a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), and a hash of a random string is no better than just using a random string. The hash adds literally no value.

Comment: I`ve done this protection on my own site. Additionally, U can either add into session 'csrf_timer=time()+30 // wich is now + 30 secs'  and then check the csrf and csrf_time remaining
So it can be useful when U afraid that potential cracker may try to get generated UID and send it to server.